# Fourier transform for constructible sheaves on spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, constructible-sheaves

Let $S_1 = S_2 = S^d$ be two copies of the $d$-dimensional sphere. Let $p_i : S_1 \times S_2 \to S_i$ be the projection, $j : U \to S_1 \times S_2$ the inclusion of the complement of the diagonal and $q_i : U \to S_i$ the restriction of $p_i$.

I want to know how to get the following formula for a constructible sheaf $\mathcal F \in D^b(Sh(S^d))$ : $${q_2}_! q_1^*(\mathcal F) \cong {p_2}_* (p_1^* \mathcal F \otimes j_! \mathbb Q_U[1])$$ It looks like some kind of base change but I don't understand where the $[1]$-shift is coming from.

Comment: What is the source of the claim that there is a $[1]$ shift here? Could it be simply two different conventions?

Comment: @WillSawin : "Perverse schobers" by Kapranov-Schechtman ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2772)). The claim is in the middle of the proof of prop 1.11 ("To see this, we write the functor in the RHS ...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $q_1 = p_1 \circ j$ and $q_2 = p_2 \circ j$ so

$$ {q_2}_! q_1^*(\mathcal F) \cong {p_2}_! j_! j^* p_1^*(\mathcal F) \cong   {p_2}_! j_! ( j^* p_1^*(\mathcal F) \otimes \mathbb Q_U) \ \cong   {p_2}_!  (  p_1^*(\mathcal F) \otimes j_! \mathbb Q_U)  $$ where the last isomorphism is the projection formula (indeed a variant of proper base change).

I do not know where the $[1]$ shift is coming from either. It seems to me that ${p_2}_!  (  p_1^*(\mathcal F) \otimes j_! \mathbb Q_U[1])$ is the correct formula for $SR$ so the earlier formula should be $T_1(\mathcal F) =  q_{2!} (q_1^* \mathcal F [1])$.

Also the shift appearing in the formula for $T_1'$ should be $[d-1]$, with the $[d]$ coming from the shift in $L$ (which I think should be $[d]$ instead of $[-d]$).

With these shifts, I can calculate that that they are quasi-inverses following the suggested approach. So one possible interpretation is that the claims are morally right but the shifts are all wrong. (Or maybe my claims are morally right but the shifts are all wrong.)

Comment: The equation (4.2), where this idea is actually used in the paper is, in your notation, $q_{2!} q_1^* \mathcal F[-1]$, which seems to be a third normalization.